# Create plot with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization

I am new to ggplot2 graphics in R. I need to create a graph in the picture.

[image]

It's comparison between sensitivity and specificity for each rule. I have 20 rules for each model on average. It is easiest way to compare quality of generated rules than searching results in tables.

my input will be data frame with 3 columns: 1 character(or factor) and 2 numeric.

this is my R version and OS:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
OS X 10.12.2 (Sierra).
ggplot2_2.1.0
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I answered your question, but for the next time you should have an example dataset :D

Comment: Thank you for the answer and advice :D

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it

```
library(ggplot2)

df<- data.frame(rule = c("rule 1", "rule 2", "rule 1"), value = c(-0.8, 0.55, 0.8), qualityMeasure = c("FPR", "TPR", "TPR"))

dat1 <- subset(df,value >= 0)
dat2 <- subset(df,value < 0)

ggplot() + geom_bar(data = dat2, stat = "identity", aes(x = rule, y = value, fill = qualityMeasure)) + geom_bar(data = dat1, stat = "identity", aes(x = rule, y = value, fill = qualityMeasure)) + coord_flip()
```